# Divide a string into smaller parts & organize a structure (C-programming)

Tags: c, string, struct, split, calloc

I am still learning C and I'm having some trouble figuring out how to handle this. Well, I have two structs:

```
struct myStruct {
    ...
    struct myString *text[5];
    ...
} allStructs;

struct myString {
    char part[100];
};
```

The objective is to have `allStruct[n]` point to 5 different parts of a text divided into lines of 100 chars each. So I allocate the space:

```
allStructs = calloc(n, sizeof(allStructs));
```

Then, assume that I have a filled `char text[500]` that I want to divide into 5 parts, and have `allStructs[n].text[n].part` point at a given part of the text. Can anyone help me with how I proceed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: you can not with this because you have not consider the '\0' character to terminate each string.

Longer answer:
Change structs like that to have more flexibility:

```
struct myStruct {
   struct myString *text;
}
struct myString {
   char *part;
}
```

The allocation should be:

```
struct myStruct *allStruct = calloc(n, sizeof(struct myStruct));
```

So you have a pointer/array on n struct myStruct.

Then initialize all members of allStruct;

```
for( i=0; i<n; ++i )
{
   allStruct[i].text = calloc(5, sizeof(myString));
   // Following for only needed if you want new strings by using the strncpy (see above)
   for( y=0; y<5; ++y )
   {
      allSTruct[i].text[y].part = calloc(101, sizeof(char));
   }
}
```

Now you have all vars initialized.

To copy your 500-chars long string into allStruct[n]:

```
for( i=0; i<5; i++ )
{
   allStructs[n].text[i].part = &text[i*100]; // If you want to point on the existing string
   // OR
   strncpy(allStructs[n].text[i].part, &text[i*100], 100); // If you want to have new strings

   // In all case, terminate the string with '\0'
   allStructs[n].text[i].part[100] = '\0';
}
```

This should work.

Comment: This looks promising! Thanks Patrice. I'll give it a try and get back to you :)

Answer (score 0):

Well, c strings are just an array of characters terminated by the null character (`'\0'`). So you would want to iterate through the large `text[500]` array putting 100 characters in each of the `myString` parts. Bare in mind that since c strings are null terminated you will only be able to store 99 characters in `char part[100]`.

Also if you wanted to only end a part on a white space character (space (`' '`), new line (`'\n'`) or tab (`'\t'`)) you would have to find the nearest one to the 100 character limit and split the string up there.

Answer (score 0):

`allStructs` is an object of type `struct myStruct`. You cannot "reassign" it with `calloc()`.

Your object `allStructs` has the member `text` which is an array of 5 pointers.
You need to set those pointers to point at specific objects of the `struct myString` type.

After you copy characters from `char text[500]` to the various `struct myString` objects, everything will work right.

**pseudo code**

```
struct myString part1;
struct myString part2;
struct myStruct allstructs;
allStructs.text[0] = &part1;
allStructs.text[1] = &part2;
strncpy(part1.part, text, 99);
part1.part[99] = '\0';

printf("part2: %s\n", allStructs.text[1].text);
```

*Oh! And don't confuse `allStructs` (ends with 's') with `allStruct` (no 's')*